Motions for moving to the middle of text objects like words, lines and paragraphs?
I can use 0 and $ to move to the start and end of the line, and w and b to move between words, but what about moving to the middle of words and lines?

To the middle of lines, words, or between words? Please [edit] to clarify. (Note that plugin requests are off-topic, so I’ve removed that. Answers may still suggest plugins however.)

The middle of words and lines.

Are you asking if they exist? If so, you can answer that yourself with a cursory look at :help index or :help motion.txt. Or are you asking if some plugin provides them? If so, you can answer that yourself by browsing the "scripts" section of vim.org. Or are you asking us to create them for you? If so, how about you try something first?

Answer
There is no built-in "middle-of-word" concept in Vim.
Discussion
However, you could create a plugin to do this. For example, here is a mapping that can move forward to the middle of the next word by using the following steps:

Move to the beginning of the next word (like w)
Calculate the length of the word, divide by 2, and round down
Move forward that many characters

vim.keymap.set('n', 'L', function()
    vim.cmd('normal! w')
    local steps = math.floor(vim.fn.strlen(vim.fn.expand('<cword>')) / 2)
    if steps > 0 then
        vim.cmd('normal! ' .. steps .. 'l')
    end
end)

Of course, there are a lot of questions that would need to be answered. Imagine that your file looks like this:
foo() {
    // the capricious vermillion fox jumps
}

If the cursor is under the v in vermillion, then the mapping above will move you to the o in fox. But if your cursor is under the   right before the v, then it will move you to the first l in vermillion. That doesn't sound quite right to me, but you would have to define the behavior yourself. Does it go to the middle of the next word, or the middle of the current word, or forward to the next middle-of-word, etc. What if the cursor is on the last character of a word?

Personally, I would expect "next word" to be "wherever w takes me."

Right, but the question is about "moving to the middle of words." Does that mean wherever w takes you + half of the word you end up on when you get there? That's why my mapping does. But maybe @Oneechan69 wants "move to middle of current word" which could be forward or backward depending on the position. Or maybe they want "move to the next beginning-of-word OR middle-of-word, whichever comes first" like a key you would press twice to get a full word ahead (moving 1/2 word at a time). My point is the behavior isn't fully specified; developing a plugin for this would take some careful thought

strlen() counts bytes, so the code fails for anything except 7-bit ASCII.
